# Get id of the next column in Gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

[image][image]

I have to get the ID attribute of the Column to **COPY & Paste column** on click of the Getform column..  Here is code for the GetForm Click

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LnkGet" OnClientClick="GetID();" runat="server" 
          CommandName="GetUrl" Font-Underline="False">Get Form</asp:LinkButton>
```

JS Code:-

```
 function GetID() {
     //Do something here
     // console.log(a);
  }
```

Please guide me a line

Comment: you want to fetch the textbox id  when  `GetForm` link button gets clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET Gridview is rendered as `HTML table`, you can simply use the `closest` & `next` method of jQuery to find the text:-

Assign a class to your LinkButton:-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkGet" CssClass="clsLnkGet" runat="server" CommandName="GetUrl" 
     Font-Underline="False">Get Form</asp:LinkButton>
```

Simply write the event handler with jQuery:-

```
$('.clsLnkGet').click(function(){
     var td = $(this).closest('td').next();
     var UrlToCopyPaste = $('input[type="text"]', td).val();
     alert(UrlToCopyPaste);
 });
```

Comment: let me give a try with this

Comment: Click to Copy  ... it is returning this values, instead of iframe text

Comment: @Jot - Okay then you need to investigate your mark-up. How it is rendering cz I can't help you without seeing what is actually rendering. But this is the way to go.

Comment: I am adding the image that is showing what is renderred inside the html console

Comment: id = ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_change_me_0 

I need to get this attribute as i am using master page so i am unable to get this chnaged id evrytime

Comment: @Jot - Duh! Sorry, you don't need a `text()` there. Basically What we are doing is finding the next `td` and finally finding the textbox inside that td. Check my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87250/discussion-between-jot-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: can you please move to chat room

Answer (score 0):

May be this help you....

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" onclick="LinkButton1_Click"" runat="server" CommandName="GetUrl" Font-Underline="False">Get Form</asp:LinkButton>
```

asp.net code

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
GridViewRow grv = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
string id = grv.Cells[0].Text;
}
```